# Civi Report Errors

Tags: wordpress

WordPress v6.4.3 CiviCRM v5.71.1 PHP 8.1

Happens on ALL reports when I click view, the report name, or try to print. I can download csv, pdf, etc. no problem.

Unable to load template 'file:CRM/Report/Form/Actions-civiexportexcel.tpl'

SmartyException: "Unable to load template 'file:CRM/Report/Form/Actions-civiexportexcel.tpl'"

#0 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(232): Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
#1 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(116): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->_execute()
#2 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Region.php(81): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch()
#3 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Region.php(157): CRM_Core_Region->{closure}()
#4 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty/plugins/block.crmRegion.php(26): CRM_Core_Region->render()
#5 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/06/6f/27/066f273e3bc81941e52aa247976e0c98a8a879c5_0.file.CMSPrint.tpl.php(107): smarty_block_crmRegion()
#6 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_resource_base.php(123): content_6606979e70f106_96301231()
#7 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php(114): Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode()
#8 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(216): Smarty_Template_Compiled->render()
#9 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(385): Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
#10 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/5d/90/9f/5d909f92961b431fc2d54bee9fae0a5ba90bcd2f_0.file.wordpress.tpl.php(31): Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender()
#11 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_resource_base.php(123): content_6606979e6fd910_59616770()
#12 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php(114): Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode()
#13 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(216): Smarty_Template_Compiled->render()
#14 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(232): Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
#15 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(116): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->_execute()
#16 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(117): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch()
#17 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(83): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->renderForm()
#18 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform()
#19 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle()
#20 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(355): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle()
#21 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(98): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#22 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Page/Instance.php(75): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run()
#23 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(323): CRM_Report_Page_Instance->run()
#24 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()
#25 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()
#26 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1231): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()
#27 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#28 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#29 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#30 /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action()
#31 {main}

Print Error

Type    DB_Error
Code    -1
Message DB Error: unknown error
Mode    16
UserInfo    INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_tmp_e_logsummary_f95db9d2fbd26ef6a252e33c2c3825e4 SELECT entity_log_civireport.id as log_civicrm_entity_id, 1, entity_log_civireport.log_action as log_civicrm_entity_log_action, 'log_civicrm_value_contact_areas' as log_civicrm_entity_log_type, entity_log_civireport.log_user_id as log_civicrm_entity_log_user_id, entity_log_civireport.log_date as log_civicrm_entity_log_date, modified_contact_civireport.display_name as log_civicrm_entity_altered_contact, modified_contact_civireport.id as log_civicrm_entity_altered_contact_id, entity_log_civireport.log_conn_id as log_civicrm_entity_log_conn_id, modified_contact_civireport.is_deleted as log_civicrm_entity_is_deleted, altered_by_contact_civireport.display_name as altered_by_contact_display_name FROM `xxxxxxxxx_wp2`.log_civicrm_value_contact_areas entity_log_civireport INNER JOIN civicrm_contact modified_contact_civireport ON (entity_log_civireport.entity_id = modified_contact_civireport.id ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_contact altered_by_contact_civireport ON (entity_log_civireport.log_user_id = altered_by_contact_civireport.id) WHERE ( 1 ) AND (entity_log_civireport.log_action != 'Initialization') GROUP BY entity_log_civireport.log_conn_id, entity_log_civireport.log_user_id, EXTRACT(DAY_MICROSECOND FROM entity_log_civireport.log_date), entity_log_civireport.id ORDER BY entity_log_civireport.log_date DESC [nativecode=1114 ** The table 'civicrm_tmp_e_logsummary_f95db9d2fbd26ef6a252e33c2c3825e4' is full]
DebugInfo   INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_tmp_e_logsummary_f95db9d2fbd26ef6a252e33c2c3825e4 SELECT entity_log_civireport.id as log_civicrm_entity_id, 1, entity_log_civireport.log_action as log_civicrm_entity_log_action, 'log_civicrm_value_contact_areas' as log_civicrm_entity_log_type, entity_log_civireport.log_user_id as log_civicrm_entity_log_user_id, entity_log_civireport.log_date as log_civicrm_entity_log_date, modified_contact_civireport.display_name as log_civicrm_entity_altered_contact, modified_contact_civireport.id as log_civicrm_entity_altered_contact_id, entity_log_civireport.log_conn_id as log_civicrm_entity_log_conn_id, modified_contact_civireport.is_deleted as log_civicrm_entity_is_deleted, altered_by_contact_civireport.display_name as altered_by_contact_display_name FROM `xxxxxxxxx_wp2`.log_civicrm_value_contact_areas entity_log_civireport INNER JOIN civicrm_contact modified_contact_civireport ON (entity_log_civireport.entity_id = modified_contact_civireport.id ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_contact altered_by_contact_civireport ON (entity_log_civireport.log_user_id = altered_by_contact_civireport.id) WHERE ( 1 ) AND (entity_log_civireport.log_action != 'Initialization') GROUP BY entity_log_civireport.log_conn_id, entity_log_civireport.log_user_id, EXTRACT(DAY_MICROSECOND FROM entity_log_civireport.log_date), entity_log_civireport.id ORDER BY entity_log_civireport.log_date DESC [nativecode=1114 ** The table 'civicrm_tmp_e_logsummary_f95db9d2fbd26ef6a252e33c2c3825e4' is full]
Civi\Core\Exception\DBQueryException: DB Error: unknown error in /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 945

- DB_Error: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown
  Exception trace

## Function    Location

0   CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler()  /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:945
1   PEAR_Error->__construct()   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php:1001
2   DB_Error->__construct() /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:575
3   PEAR::_raiseError() /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:223
4   PEAR->__call()  /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php:1952
5   DB_common->raiseError() /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php:966
6   DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php:413
7   DB_mysqli->simpleQuery()    /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php:1241
8   DB_common->query()  /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:2696
9   DB_DataObject->_query() /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:1829
10  DB_DataObject->query()  /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:507
11  CRM_Core_DAO->query()   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:1764
12  CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery()    /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Logging/ReportSummary.php:385
13  CRM_Logging_ReportSummary->buildTemporaryTables()   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Logging/ReportSummary.php:428
14  CRM_Logging_ReportSummary->beginPostProcessCommon() /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php:3064
15  CRM_Report_Form->beginPostProcess() /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php:3661
16  CRM_Report_Form->postProcess()  /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php:976
17  CRM_Report_Form->preProcess()   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:748
18  CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()  /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php:76
19  CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform()    /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203
20  HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle() /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103
21  HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle()   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355
22  CRM_Core_Controller->run()  /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php:98
23  CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run()    /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Page/Instance.php:75
24  CRM_Report_Page_Instance->run() /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:323
25  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()  /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69
26  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()  /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36
27  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()   /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1231
28  CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke() /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:324
29  WP_Hook->apply_filters()    /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:348
30  WP_Hook->do_action()    /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:517
31  do_action() /home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php:259
32  {main}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is available on the gitlab but the maintainer as not yet released it.

You can download the code [from the gitlab](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civiexportexcel/-/archive/master/civiexportexcel-master.zip) and copy the /vendor folder from older version into the downloaded version or run composer install inside the extension folder

Comment: Shows Page Not Found. I tracked it down though. I have v2.5 and it shows no update in the Extensions or on the main page. On the GitLab page looks like there is an info.xml that says "bump version 2.6" So should I download this, delete the Extension in my dir and then install this new one? Also, I have the Smarty v3 and saw this issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civiexportexcel/-/issues/21

Comment: Nope on the v3 removal from civicrm.settings.php

Comment: Have updated my answer

Comment: I am going to mark your solution as the answer as it correct. I am going to stick with mine for me, though, as I am not too good at moving things all around. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was simply to disable the CiviCRM Export to Excel. Reports work perfect now. It is similar to the issue here:

https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civiexportexcel/-/issues/21

But different in that I am pretty well updated and it didn't fix the errors on the Extension.

I can convert on the fly so will check back on the extension down the road.